# PHP/HTML Table populated by MySQL only showing one result

Tags: php

I have created a table to be automatically populated by a MySQL table, it only slightly works though. It loads one result, but no more. I need it to display all results in the mysql table.

Below is my Query + Array

```
  $future = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Future");
  $future_row = mysql_fetch_array($future);
```

This is my table Code

```
<div class="tg-wrap"><table class="tg" style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 1000px;>

            <tr class="header">
                <th class="tg-ls31" colspan="2">Device</th>
                <th class="tg-ls31" colspan="2">Booked By</th>
                <th class="tg-ls31" colspan="2">Date Out</th>
                <th class="tg-ls31" colspan="2">Date Back</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
                {
                   echo "<tr>";
                   echo "<td class='tg-baqh' colspan='2'>".$future_row[Device]."</td>";
                   echo "<td class='tg-baqh' colspan='2'>".$future_row[Name]."</td>";
                   echo "<td class='tg-baqh' colspan='2'>".$future_row[Out]."</td>";
                   echo "<td class='tg-baqh' colspan='2'>".$future_row[In]."</td>";
                   echo "</tr>";
               }

            ?>
        </table></div>
```

If you could provide a fix so that I can display more than one result in this table, i'd be most appreciative.

**EDIT 1:**

I have updated the code, removed the first array and created a while loop

```
<?php while( $future_row = mysql_fetch_array($future))
                {
                   echo "<tr>";
                   echo "<td class='tg-baqh' colspan='2'>".$future_row[Device]."</td>";
                   echo "<td class='tg-baqh' colspan='2'>".$future_row[Name]."</td>";
                   echo "<td class='tg-baqh' colspan='2'>".$future_row[Out]."</td>";
                   echo "<td class='tg-baqh' colspan='2'>".$future_row[In]."</td>";
                   echo "</tr>";
               }

            ?>
```

I have also had a request for an image of the table, which I have provided below

[image: Image of the MySQL DB Table]

**EDIT 2:**

I have been requested to provide the full page code, which i will provide below.

```
    <head>
<?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "gunner98";

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("laptop_pool",$dbhandle)
  or die("Could not select database");

//execute the SQL query and return records
$P1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM P1");
$P1_row = mysql_fetch_array($P1);

$P2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM P2");
$P2_row = mysql_fetch_array($P2);

$P3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM P3");
$P3_row = mysql_fetch_array($P3);

$P4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM P4");
$P4_row = mysql_fetch_array($P4);

$P5 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM P5");
$P5_row = mysql_fetch_array($P5);

$P6 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM P6");
$P6_row = mysql_fetch_array($P6);

$P7 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM P7");
$P7_row = mysql_fetch_array($P7);

$future = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Future");
$future_row4 = mysql_fetch_array($future);


//close the connection
mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>

<title>&nbsp;&nbsp;Moat Laptop Pool Table&nbsp;&nbsp;</title>

</head>

<body style="background-height: 100%;background-width: 100%;background: #141E30;background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #141E30 , #243B55);background: linear-gradient(to left, #141E30 , #243B55);">

<div id="top" style="position: fixed;top: 0;left: 0;z-index: 999;width: 100%;height: 25px;">

<div id="alert_box" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; color: white; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);">

<div id="Site_Alert" style="font-weight: bold; display: inline;width: 5%;float: left;">
&nbsp;Site Alert:
</div>

<div id="scroll_alert" style="display: inline; float: right; width:95%;">
<marquee behavior=scroll direction="left" scrollamount="8" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">This is in development!</marquee>
</div>

</div>

<div id="logo" style="font-family: Tw Cen MT; font-weight: Bold; position: fixed; color: white; left: 650px;top: 35px; font-size: 80px;text-shadow: 3px 3px #c7c7c7;">
Moat Laptop Pool Table
</div>

<div id="content_box" style="position: fixed; left: 450px;top: 135px; width:60%; height: 70%; border-radius: 3px;

">

<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border-color:#ccc;margin:0px auto;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#ccc;color:#333;background-color:#fff;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:#ccc;color:#333;background-color:#f0f0f0;}
.tg .tg-baqh{text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-ls31{font-weight:bold;background-color:#333333;color:#f0f0f0;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
th.tg-sort-header::-moz-selection { background:transparent; }th.tg-sort-header::selection      { background:transparent; }th.tg-sort-header { cursor:pointer; }table th.tg-sort-header:after {  content:'';  float:right;  margin-top:7px;  border-width:0 4px 4px;  border-style:solid;  border-color:#404040 transparent;  visibility:hidden;  }table th.tg-sort-header:hover:after {  visibility:visible;  }table th.tg-sort-desc:after,table th.tg-sort-asc:after,table th.tg-sort-asc:hover:after {  visibility:visible;  opacity:0.4;  }table th.tg-sort-desc:after {  border-bottom:none;  border-width:4px 4px 0;  }@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {.tg {width: auto !important;}.tg col {width: auto !important;}.tg-wrap {overflow-x: auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;margin: auto 0px;}}</style>
<div class="tg-wrap"><table id="tg-4b5Id" class="tg" style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 1000px; ">
<colgroup>
<col style="width: 29px">
<col style="width: 51px">
<col style="width: 35px">
<col style="width: 53px">
<col style="width: 28px">
<col style="width: 77px">
<col style="width: 58px">
<col style="width: 94px">
<col style="width: 44px">
<col style="width: 133px">
<col style="width: 37px">
<col style="width: 91px">
</colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-ls31" colspan="2">Device</th>
    <th class="tg-ls31" colspan="2">Out or In</th>
    <th class="tg-ls31" colspan="2">Out on</th>
    <th class="tg-ls31" colspan="2">In Posession Of</th>
    <th class="tg-ls31" colspan="2">Department</th>
    <th class="tg-ls31" colspan="2">Due Back</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2">P1</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P1_row['status'];
?> </td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P1_row['left'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P1_row['posession'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P1_row['department'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P1_row['returns'];
?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2">P2</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P2_row['status'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P2_row['left'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P2_row['posession'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P2_row['department'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P2_row['returns'];
?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2">P3</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P3_row['status'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P3_row['left'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P3_row['posession'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P3_row['department'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P3_row['returns'];
?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2">P4</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P4_row['status'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P4_row['left'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P4_row['posession'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P4_row['department'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P4_row['returns'];
?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2">P5</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P5_row['status'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P5_row['left'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P5_row['posession'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P5_row['department'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P5_row['returns'];
?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2">P6</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P6_row['status'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P6_row['left'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P6_row['posession'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P6_row['department'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P6_row['returns'];
?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2">P7</td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P7_row['status'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P7_row['left'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P7_row['posession'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P7_row['department'];
?></td>
    <td class="tg-baqh" colspan="2"><?php
echo $P7_row['returns'];
?></td>
  </tr>
</table></div>
<div id="future" style="font-family: Tw Cen MT; font-weight: Bold; position: fixed; color: white; left: 750px; font-size: 80px;text-shadow: 3px 3px #c7c7c7;">
Future Bookings
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div class="tg-wrap"><table class="tg" style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 1000px;>

            <tr class="header">
                <th class="tg-ls31" colspan="2">Device</th>
                <th class="tg-ls31" colspan="2">Booked By</th>
                <th class="tg-ls31" colspan="2">Date Out</th>
                <th class="tg-ls31" colspan="2">Date Back</th>
            </tr>
            <?php while( $future_row = mysql_fetch_array($future))
                {
                   echo "<tr>";
                   echo "<td class='tg-baqh' colspan='2'>".$future_row[Device]."</td>";
                   echo "<td class='tg-baqh' colspan='2'>".$future_row[Name]."</td>";
                   echo "<td class='tg-baqh' colspan='2'>".$future_row[Out]."</td>";
                   echo "<td class='tg-baqh' colspan='2'>".$future_row[In]."</td>";
                   echo "</tr>";
               }

            ?>
        </table></div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">var TgTableSort=window.TgTableSort||function(n,t){"use strict";function r(n,t){for(var e=[],o=n.childNodes,i=0;i<o.length;++i){var u=o[i];if("."==t.substring(0,1)){var a=t.substring(1);f(u,a)&&e.push(u)}else u.nodeName.toLowerCase()==t&&e.push(u);var c=r(u,t);e=e.concat(c)}return e}function e(n,t){var e=[],o=r(n,"tr");return o.forEach(function(n){var o=r(n,"td");t>=0&&t<o.length&&e.push(o[t])}),e}function o(n){return n.textContent||n.innerText||""}function i(n){return n.innerHTML||""}function u(n,t){var r=e(n,t);return r.map(o)}function a(n,t){var r=e(n,t);return r.map(i)}function c(n){var t=n.className||"";return t.match(/\S+/g)||[]}function f(n,t){return-1!=c(n).indexOf(t)}function s(n,t){f(n,t)||(n.className+=" "+t)}function d(n,t){if(f(n,t)){var r=c(n),e=r.indexOf(t);r.splice(e,1),n.className=r.join(" ")}}function v(n){d(n,L),d(n,E)}function l(n,t,e){r(n,"."+E).map(v),r(n,"."+L).map(v),e==T?s(t,E):s(t,L)}function g(n){return function(t,r){var e=n*t.str.localeCompare(r.str);return 0==e&&(e=t.index-r.index),e}}function h(n){return function(t,r){var e=+t.str,o=+r.str;return e==o?t.index-r.index:n*(e-o)}}function m(n,t,r){var e=u(n,t),o=e.map(function(n,t){return{str:n,index:t}}),i=e&&-1==e.map(isNaN).indexOf(!0),a=i?h(r):g(r);return o.sort(a),o.map(function(n){return n.index})}function p(n,t,r,o){for(var i=f(o,E)?N:T,u=m(n,r,i),c=0;t>c;++c){var s=e(n,c),d=a(n,c);s.forEach(function(n,t){n.innerHTML=d[u[t]]})}l(n,o,i)}function x(n,t){var r=t.length;t.forEach(function(t,e){t.addEventListener("click",function(){p(n,r,e,t)}),s(t,"tg-sort-header")})}var T=1,N=-1,E="tg-sort-asc",L="tg-sort-desc";return function(t){var e=n.getElementById(t),o=r(e,"tr"),i=o.length>0?r(o[0],"td"):[];0==i.length&&(i=r(o[0],"th"));for(var u=1;u<o.length;++u){var a=r(o[u],"td");if(a.length!=i.length)return}x(e,i)}}(document);document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(n){TgTableSort("tg-4b5Id")});</script>
</div>




</body>
```

Not the cleanest of code at the moment, but I want to get it functional before I clean it up.

Comment: `$future_row4` != `$future_row`. Did you copy/paste?

Comment: @JayBlanchard No, as i referenced it somewhere else, i added the 4 to make sure it didn't conflict, it was to create that loop. However, I just added another entry to the table, which showed up. Seemingly, the first row isn't being picked up in the table. All other rows are, to fix this, i've just added a blank row, and it all seems to now be working.

Comment: I don't understand, because you're not using `$future_row4` to diplay the table and I do not see it referenced anywhere else in the code. Did you go back and quote the identifiers?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I was using it to display the table, so added the 4 to avoid conflict with the loop, that was the only time used. What do you mean?

Comment: I edited my answer. Comment out `$future_row4 = mysql_fetch_array($future);` It is eating the first row of the results.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Oh that fixed that, Cheers, this is all sorted now. A quick question, i know there is a way as i've used it on one of my older projects but i've forgotten what is was. How would i remove an option from an input select (dropdown), automatically if it is already booked into the MySQL db?

Comment: How are you building the drop-down?

Comment: @JayBlanchard `<b><legend>Desired Device</legend></b>
      <select name="device">
     <option value="P1">P1</option>
     <option value="P2">P2</option>
     <option value="P3">P3</option>
     <option value="P4">P4</option>
     <option value="P5">P5</option>
     <option value="P6">P6</option>
     <option value="P7">P7</option>
    </select>`

Comment: To do what you want requires JavaScript - http://stackoverflow.com/q/4571602/1011527

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, some warnings:

***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

---

You have to loop through your results to populate the table:

```
$future = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Future");
```

Now, in the table, you loop (make sure to quote the array identifiers):

```
<div class="tg-wrap"><table class="tg" style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 1000px;>

            <tr class="header">
                <th class="tg-ls31" colspan="2">Device</th>
                <th class="tg-ls31" colspan="2">Booked By</th>
                <th class="tg-ls31" colspan="2">Date Out</th>
                <th class="tg-ls31" colspan="2">Date Back</th>
            </tr>
            <?php
                while($future_row = mysql_fetch_array($future)) {
                   echo "<tr>";
                   echo "<td class='tg-baqh' colspan='2'>".$future_row['Device']."</td>";
                   echo "<td class='tg-baqh' colspan='2'>".$future_row['Name']."</td>";
                   echo "<td class='tg-baqh' colspan='2'>".$future_row['Out']."</td>";
                   echo "<td class='tg-baqh' colspan='2'>".$future_row['In']."</td>";
                   echo "</tr>";
               }

            ?>
        </table></div>
```

---

**EDIT -**

Now that I see your full code after the edit I see that you are assigning the first row of data here:

```
$future_row4 = mysql_fetch_array($future);
```

So when you do the while loop later on:

```
while($future_row = mysql_fetch_array($future)) {...
```

you will only get the remaining rows in the table. Remove (or comment out) the first assignment and your table will contain all of the rows.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer. My server is currently running PHP 5 instead of 7, so they should still function efficiently. I have included this loop, and it's only populating one field, I need it to include all of the data inside the mysql table, not just one row.

Comment: Can you add your MySQL table configuration to your original post?

Comment: and also can u include your updated code in the question

Comment: @JayBlanchard Done

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Done

Comment: Which row is being output @JamesTimms?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Currently Row 2 - Sally R.

Comment: Is there some other PHP code in your script? Are you showing us everything? Did you go back and quote the array identifiers? Are there any errors in the error logs?

Comment: what do u get when u `var_dump()` the results?

Comment: I think the OP has disappeared @MasivuyeCokile

Comment: Looks like that @JayBlanchard even on he's question before this he did the same

Comment: @JayBlanchard There are two tables on the page so to save confusion I included only thetable that it's regarding and the related array. If you want me to, i can provide the full code on the original question.

Comment: Yes, please do. I just want to make sure one is not interfering with the other.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have provided the code for you. It's not the cleanest of code right now, but I always clean after the project is functional

Comment: Finally located the issue @MasivuyeCokile

Answer (score 0):

use while loop .

```
<?php
         while( $future_row = mysql_fetch_array($future))
                {
```

Comment: I have included the while loop, but it has not fixed the issue.