# Remove selected Options in the next select field using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have about 10 select boxes added to a form using a loop. All with the same number of options.

```
 <?php
            for($i=1; $i<11; $i++){
            ?>
            <select name="doc[]"; id="doc<?php echo $i?>"; autocomplete="off"; 
 onchange='disable()'  required>
                <option value="none" disabled selected>Select</option>
                <option value=0>A</option>
                <option value=1>B</option>
                <option value=2>C</option>
                <option value=3>D</option>
                <option value=4>E</option>
                <option value=5>F</option>
                <option value=6>G</option>
                <option value=7>H</option>
                <option value=8>I</option>
                </select>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
```

I want if I select first option in first select box, the next select box should not have that option. In pure Javascript, not Jquery.

I have tried writing something like:

```
function disable(){
    for(var i=1; i<9; i++){
        var val = document.getElementById('doc'+i).value;
        document.getElementById("doc"+(i+1)).options[val].disabled = 
        true;
        }
}
```

But it is not working as I expected.

Comment: OK, so what have you tried?

Comment: @ j08691, I have added my javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so many hours of trying as a novice, I have managed to fix this by modifying and re-modifying the JS code and finally ending with the following: There were 10 select menus, so I have changed the loop variable total to `<11`

```
function disable(){
    
    for(var i=1; i<11; i++){
        var doc = document.getElementById('doc'+i);
         var changesource=event.target.id || event.srcElement.id;
        if(changesource==doc.id){
            var val = doc.selectedIndex;
            
            for(var m=i+1; m<11; m++){
                document.getElementById('doc'+m).options[val].remove();
            }
            
            
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }
       

    }
}
```

Comment: glad to hear that. also, mark your own answer as accepted for people in the future with the same problem. It will make it easier for them to find the solution. welcome to stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this has to be done in some steps.

1. Getting the value of the selected option:

   ```
    var select = document.getElementById("doc1");
    var value = select.value;
   ```
2. Fire a change event when you select an option:

   let doc = document.querySelector('#doc1');
   doc.addEventListener('change', function() {
   document.getElementById("doc2").options[value ] = null;
   })
3. You use this to your own liking, using array map or loop to set up the serial of select boxes in any way you want.
   A word of advice, you probably should try around with javascript a bit more before attempting more advanced codes since I see no indication that you tried a solution at all. It is ok to be a novice, we all were there one time. But I really suggest you take a look at this and try it your own way. It is not exactly a duplicate since it deals with only two dropdowns, but it is a start and will give you a basic idea of what you are doing. ([How do I remove options from a dropdownlist in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571602/how-do-i-remove-options-from-a-dropdownlist-in-javascript))

Comment: I have added my Javascript code. Looking at your answer, I am seeing it is basically the same as mine, save for `null`, which is `disabled` in my JS code. I am a novice yes. I only learn coding to develop small solutions for my private business.

Comment: @ساميأوكتش from what I see in your code, it is simply running through the entire list at the start of the form loading. When this function is running, 
var val = document.getElementById('doc'+i).value;
is actually empty since you havent actually selected anything. you need to take the value of the selected dropdown AFTER you have actually selected an option. 
doc.addEventListener('change', function() { // do something})  is VITAL here.

Comment: Mash, there is an `onchange` in my `HTML tag` with a call to a `disable` function. Maybe what I forgot to add in my JS code is the function itself. I have edited it again to include the function. I think with the function put before the loop, then the `val` won't be empty. Or will it?